# df delete rows on conditon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 3 columns and signal has 2 values either on or off.
Timestamp. Name. Signal

I want to delete wrong assigned signal values and I apply this to df:

```
for i in np.arange(0,len(df)-1):
  if (df.loc[i,'Signal']=='On' & 
  df.loc[i+1,'Signal']!='On' & 
  df.loc[i-1,'Signal']!='On'):
     df.drop(i,inplace=True)
```

However here I can delete only single value which appears in between Off values. For example:

```
Signal
 Off
 On
 Off
 Off
```

But I want to delete cases like below as well:

```
Signal 
 Off
 Off
 Off
 On
 On
 Off
 Off
```

With my code here only first "on" value will be deleted.

How can I solve it correctly?

Comment: you need to provide sample data as df

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
s = df['Signal']
mask = df.groupby(['Name', s.ne(s.shift(1)).cumsum()], sort=False, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x['Signal'].eq('On').sum() in (1, 2)] * len(x))).reset_index(drop=True) & (~df.groupby('Name')['Signal'].shift().isna())
df = df[~mask]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I want to keep the first row for each unique Name

Comment: @Elgun check now.

Comment: In before after example that you provided as you see only On values which are in between Off values are dropped. but i explained in my post that I want also to delete the ones which are not only single On values in between Off vakues but also 2 On On values in between Off values

Comment: In example that you provided rows 3 and 4 also should be deleted

Comment: Except very first one. All other cases which are single or double On values between Off values should be replaced with Off values.

Comment: Basicly for each Name after grouping it first value of signal always should be kept but all other single or double On values should be replaced with Off.